# searching for a server on local network

Tags: server, client, p2p

I want to make a chat app, the app would not have a fixed server to connect to, the server is can be started (or always running) on the device like a p2p connection

i need some sort of a network discovery method that can do that for me, i understand there isna protocol to do that but i don't know what it is or if i could even use it to do what i want..

i thought of just pinging every IP for a port to check but you can not ping ports, and trying to establish a connection with every IP on the network is not an effiecent idea..

google is not helping, I get very far topics from what i want.

i have a network management OS named MikroTek if it would help, you can't really install things on it but has almost every networking tool you would probably need.

please help?
how can i go about this? i just need a lead to a way or a name of a protocol or anything that can help me achieve this, would be most appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use IP multicast via UDP multicast sockets. For IPv4 pick an administratively scoped address and a port, for v6 you have have more fine-grained choices wrt. scopes. And then devise a protocol to announce the presence of your software to peers in the network.